# Nested for loop leading to: Error in [<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*` replacement has x rows, data has y

Tags: r

I have 6 data frames (dfs) with a lot of data of different biological groups and another 6 data frames (tax.dfs) with taxonomical information about those groups. I want to replace a column of each of the 6 dfs with a column with the scientific name of each species present in the 6 tax.dfs. 
To do that I created two lists of the data frames and I'm trying to apply a nested for loop:

```
dfs <- list(df.birds, df.mammals, df.crocs, df.snakes, df.turtles, df.lizards)

tax.dfs <- list(tax.birds,tax.mammals, tax.crocs, tax.snakes, tax.turtles, tax.lizards )

for(i in dfs){

for(y in tax.dfs){

 i[,1] <- y[,2]

}}
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 1, value = c("Aotus trivirgatus",  : 
  replacement has 64 rows, data has 43
```

But both data frames have the same number of rows, I actually used dfs to create tax.dfs applying the tnrs_match_names function from rotl package.

Any suggestions of how I could fix this error or that help me to find another way to do what I need to will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: How do you want to use those six dataframes in the end? What you are asking can be achieved quite easily, but I wonder if you wouldn't rather want to end up with one big dataframe for all animals that includes all this information.

Comment: Also, could you please post `dput(head(df.birds))` and the same for mammals and crocs. That would really help us help you. :)

Comment: Also, the output of  `lapply(dfs, dim)` and `lapply(tax.dfs, dim)` would be helpful.

Comment: Hello, @coffeinjunky. Thanks for your answer, your code worked perfectly for what I needed!!
I already have all the data in just one big data frame, but I'm working with phylogenetically correct analyses, and I had to separate in 6 data frames according to the groups because, in this type of analyses, I have to generate a phylogenetic tree for each taxonomical group independently that will be used for the correction of the lack of independence of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, to iterate over two objects simultaneously, the following works:

Example Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1, b=2)
df2 <- data.frame(c=3, d=4)
df3 <- data.frame(e=5, f=6)

df_1 <- data.frame(a='A', b='B')
df_2 <- data.frame(c='C', d='D')
df_3 <- data.frame(e='E', f='F')

dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
df_s <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3)
```

Using mapply:

```
out <- mapply(function(one, two) {
  one[,1] <- two[,2]
  return(one)
}, dfs, df_s, SIMPLIFY = F )

out

[[1]]
  a b
1 B 2

[[2]]
  c d
1 D 4

[[3]]
  e f
1 F 6
```

Here, `one` and `two` in `mapply` correspond to the different elements in `dfs` and `df_s`. Having said that, let's make it a bit more interesting. Let's change my third example to the following:

```
df_3 <- data.frame(e=c('E', 'e'), f=c('F', 'f'))
df_s <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3) # needs to be executed again
```

Now, let's adjust the function:

```
out <- mapply(function(one, two) {

  if(nrow(one) != nrow(two)){return('Wrong dimensions')}

    one[,1] <- two[,2]
  return(one)

}, dfs, df_s, SIMPLIFY = F )

out
[[1]]
  a b
1 B 2

[[2]]
  c d
1 D 4

[[3]]
[1] "Wrong dimensions"
```